# Best payment gateways and Rails gems for secure payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, payment-gateway

I'm developing a website in Ruby on Rails to sell valuable goods. We need to have a very secure payment system in order for people to purchase stuff online.

Companies like PayPal seem to take a big commission, so we are wondering how sites like *99 designs* or *ugallery* handle payments?

I'm a programmer, but until a year or so ago, I was entirely coding in C++. 2 months back, I switched to Rails and I have a little bit of experience in that, but I want to know what the best way is to tackle this problem. Obviously, I want to make sure that my customers know our system is fully secure, but I have 0 experience in developing commercial websites like this.

What pitfalls should we be aware of? Any examples I can look at? Are there Rails gems that we can leverage to set this up? How do we go about getting our site verified by a McAfee/Verisign/whatever (and is this necessary?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to have a secure payment system is to have as little to do with it as possible. I've heard good things about [Braintree Payments](http://www.braintreepayments.com/) -- especially about their [client libraries](http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby). (Though [Square](https://squareup.com/) definitely has the "buzz" these days as the new hip and cool payment processing vendor.)

Whoever does your purchase processing will take a cut. It's part of the convenience of not counting $100 bills and checking each one with test-pens and loupes to ensure you're not being taken.

I giggle every time I see a "Verified by McAfee" or "Verified by Verisign" logo on a web site. I don't know what they actually do to "earn" that badge, but in my mind I imagine it mostly starts and stops with a payment of $$$ and periodically checking that the site's SSL certificate hasn't expired. I can't imagine that they actually have a team of hackers looking for weaknesses in websites constantly and they absolutely cannot provide any assurances that the site *hasn't* been hacked -- unless they also provide hosting. Maybe ask your payment processor if their clients have noticed any sales increase / decrease with the little logos or if there is any actual value to these products. I doubt it, but perhaps someone else has hard numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your goals are:

[Stripe](https://stripe.com/) is great if you're looking for super easy less than an hour to setup type system. They have comparable or lower rates than you'll find else where at 2.9% + $0.30. What you'll find is other places do the same base rate, but they have monthly fees or other fees you'll have to pay. Stripe doesn't have any of these fees.

If you're looking to not get killed per transaction checkout [Dwolla](https://www.dwolla.com/dev/). They only charge .25 per transaction. The people paying on your site will need to register for a Dwolla account, but it's pretty easy to do and as it becomes more common more and more folks will have one.

Answer (score 0):

try [spree](http://railscasts.com/episodes/298-getting-started-with-spree)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of pricing, all payment gateways are more or less the same. The thing you need to worry about more is security. Your customer's confidential information would be vulnerable if you don't use secure payment gateways.

When comparing security, Stripe is the most secure platform. It provides PCI-Compliance and uses high-risk radar and 3D security to prevent malicious attacks. It charges 2.9% + 30¢ per transaction. In the second position, I would place Square, it is a powerful platform and protects customers' information through the machine learning model. Square charges 2.6% + 10¢ per transaction.

This blog regarding the `[best WooCommerce payment gateways][1]` will help in better comparison against prices and security.